Call sub from userform leads to error "not defined"
I have done this before and have no idea why it is not working. I am in Outlook VBA and have a userform with a button, that is supposed to call a public sub:
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Repaint
    
    Call FindQuotes
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub


and then in ThisOutlookSession, I have the sub defined as:
Public Sub FindQuotes()


I made the sub Public Sub so I don't know why it doesn't recognize it, any ideas?

Here's the error"


What is the error message? What line does it occur? Your Private Sub UserForm_Click() has no content...

You placed the FindQuotes subroutine in the ThisOutlookSession class module. Consequently, you need to call it using Call ThisOutlookSession.FindQuotes. A better approach is to create a separate module and place FindQuotes there. This allows you to simply use Call FindQuotes.
ThisOutlookSession: This is a special module in Outlook VBA designed to handle event-driven procedures specific to the Outlook application. It is automatically created when you access the VBA editor in Outlook and is intended for code that interacts directly with Outlook events, such as when an email is received or sent.
This module can become cluttered if overused for general-purpose code. It's best kept clean and focused on event handlers.
Standard Module: A standard module (often just referred to as a module) is a general-purpose code container. It is used to store procedures and functions that can be called from anywhere within the project. It is not tied to specific events of the Outlook application.
Standard modules help organize code logically. By separating general functions and procedures into modules, you make the code easier to maintain and understand.
Further reading: ThisOutlookSession/Events

I agree that it's not best practices, and I'm planning to move it properly after I get it all working. I did try "ThisOutlookSession.FindQuotes" but it gives me another error: "Run time error 400: Form already displayed, can't show modally". Does this mean I have another "load userform" somewhere?

Based on the code shown in the picture, the following happens: You loaded the Userform and then clicked on the button for Command1, which runs the code that calls FindQuotes. FindQuotes tries to load the Userform again, but this fails. Read here on userforms. It is also valid for Outlook.

This worked on Friday, and today that same line is giving me another error: "Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range" ... how does the "call ThisOutlookSession.FindQuotes" give me that ?

Without the code you have in place difficult to tell. You might have a look here
